# componentDidUpdate is not firing

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Is componentDidUpdate suppose to fire when I change routes using react-router? I modified the example code and can't seem to get it to work.

I made the home component log some text but it isn't firing it seems. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route,
    Link
} from 'react-router-dom'

const BasicExample = () => (
    <Router>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/topics">Topics</Link></li>
            </ul>

            <hr/>

            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
            <Route path="/topics" component={Topics}/>
        </div>
    </Router>
)

class Home extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<div>
            <h2>Home</h2>
        </div>);
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        console.log("Updated!");
    }
}


const About = () => (
    <div>
        <h2>About</h2>
    </div>
)

const Topics = ({ match }) => (
    <div>
        <h2>Topics</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <Link to={`${match.url}/rendering`}>
                    Rendering with React
                </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
                <Link to={`${match.url}/components`}>
                    Components
                </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
                <Link to={`${match.url}/props-v-state`}>
                    Props v. State
                </Link>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <Route path={`${match.url}/:topicId`} component={Topic}/>
        <Route exact path={match.url} render={() => (
            <h3>Please select a topic.</h3>
        )}/>
    </div>
)

const Topic = ({ match }) => (
    <div>
        <h3>{match.params.topicId}</h3>
    </div>
)

ReactDOM.render(
  <BasicExample />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per the [DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#updating):

> An update can be caused by changes to props or state. These methods
>   are called when a component is being re-rendered:
>
> componentWillReceiveProps()
>
> shouldComponentUpdate()
>
> componentWillUpdate()
>
> render()
>
> componentDidUpdate()

**componentWillUpdate**:

> componentWillUpdate() is invoked immediately before rendering when new
>   props or state are being received. Use this as an opportunity to
>   perform preparation before an update occurs. This method is not called
>   for the initial render.

In Home component you didn't define any `state` and you are not using any `props`also, that't why that `function` will not get called.

Check this example `componentDidUpdate` will get called when you click on Click Me text:

```js
class Home extends React.Component {
    
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {a: false}
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        console.log("Updated!");
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
               <h2>Home</h2>
               <p onClick={()=>this.setState({a: !this.state.a})}>Click Me</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Home/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: Note that `componentWillUpdate()` and `componentWillReceiveProps()` are now [deprecated](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

Comment: didn't work for me.  I'm updating state in a constructor and react-router still didn't fire off my componentDidUpdate

Answer (score -2):

Slight recommended change: Passing objects into setState methods is deprecated. Use the prevState property and flip its value.

```
class Home extends React.Component {

        constructor(){
            super();
            this.state = {a: false}
        }

        componentDidUpdate() {
            console.log("Updated!");
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                   <h2>Home</h2>
                   <p onClick={()=>this.setState((prevState) => ({a: !prevState.a}))}>Click Me</p>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }


    ReactDOM.render(<Home/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Comment: Can you give more information about "Passing objects into setState methods is deprecated"? I hadn't heard that.

Comment: Yes. And I suppose 'deprecated' is not the correct word. I should have said a 'bad habit,' and my understanding is that React is going to stop supporting passing objects into the setState method as early as React 17. This writer covers the subject pretty well here: [link] (https://daveceddia.com/why-not-modify-react-state-directly/) but essentially the state is intended to be immutable. When you pass an object into setState you're directly modifying the current state. An application this small is not going to see an impact, but it can lead to annoying and difficult to locate bugs.

Comment: P.S., I updated my recommended change to properly wrap the object implicitly returned from the call to setState in parentheses. Between the two examples, you're passing an object into setState which directly mutates its value. I am returning an object which changes the value of the state based on its most recent state, using the prevState argument as a buffer.

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding the article you are linking to. The issue in the article is the line:

this.state.cart.push(item.id);

The issue is not something like:

this.setState({foo: !this.state.foo})

The former mutates state directly. The latter uses all immutable objects.

Comment: I found a reference to what you are advising. I don't think your link above covers it. Your link is about mutation. The problem you are advising against is using this.state in the computation of the inputs to this.setState. This article advises against that: https://itnext.io/react-setstate-usage-and-gotchas-ac10b4e03d60 It says: "Due to the async nature of setState, it is not advisable to use this.state to get the previous state within setState. Instead, always rely on the prevState way"

Comment: downvoting for misleading about setState method depreciation